# Div auto width issue

Tags: css

I am working on a small php script.
But I have an issue in using this css code:

```
.wrapper{
    width:200px;
}
.lisser, .limen{
    float:right;
}
.lisser{
    width:80px;
}
.clear{
clear: both;
}
```

and this is html code :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="limen">
        piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi
    </div>
    <div class="lisser">
        psdoiusd
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I want that the limen div auto change its width without adding width parameter on his class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/efVtS/ Demo

Comment: How do you want it to look like? It’s not really clear from the question.

Comment: Do you want it to change it's width, or do you want it to have a fixed size? From fiddle, it has a fixed size.

Comment: Im using @media queries so the problem is that i want that limen div get his width automaticly so for example if the width of screen is 300px the lisser div will take 50px and the limen will take the rest !

Comment: @user3027295 He's probably not behaving because he is actually a she. ;)

Comment: Still waiting for solution !

Comment: @user3027295 Copy-paste into your fiddle, what samitha has suggested in the answer below. Is that how you want it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
    width:auto;
}
.lisser, .limen {
    float:right;
}
.lisser {
    width:auto;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: the wrapper width cannot be auto ! it depend about browser width !

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="limen" style="width:100%">
        piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi piupipoi
    </div>
    <div class="lisser">
        psdoiusd
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here if you use css style `width:100%` you can have *limen div auto change his width*. 
This was what I think you meant when you said "*auto change*"

By using `width:100%` you ask the component to take the entire width (or maximum possible) of its parent component